# Problems implementing a protocol

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am developing a game and I have a settings view that is pushed modally. I want if I turn music off in that view, stop the background music. I'm using a protocol (I am using automatic reference counting):

**game.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"
#import "stackButton.h"
#import "tvr_AppDelegate.h"

@protocol settingsChanger <NSObject>

-(void)changeSettings:(int)soundVal musicSetting:(int)musicVal;

@end
 @interface game : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, settingsChanger>{
     ...
 }
```

**game.m**

```
   -(void)changeSettings:(int)soundVal musicSetting:(int)musicVal{
    if (musicVal == 1) {
        [self playMusic];
    }else{
        [audioPlayer stop];
    }
```

**settings.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol settingsChanger;

@interface settings : UIViewController{
    id<settingsChanger> settingsDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<settingsChanger> settingsDelegate;

-(IBAction)updateMusicSetting;

@end
```

**settings.m**

```
-(IBAction)updateMusicSetting{
    tvr_AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (swMusic.on) { 
        [delegate updateMusicSetting:1];
        [settingsDelegate changeSettings:0 musicSetting:1];
    }
    else { 
        [delegate updateMusicSetting:0];
        [settingsDelegate changeSettings:0 musicSetting:0];
    }
}
```

My IBAction is triggered by a UISwitch. All goes fine, except that id settingsDelegate references to memory 0x0 and I think that's the my method changeSettings is never called in game.h. What am I missing?.

Comment: Show the code where you're setting the `settings` `delegate` to an instance of `game`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I forgot to put this before launch the settings view: settingsScreen.settingsDelegate = self;

Comment: FWIW, you almost never want your delegates declared `strong`. Almost universally, you need them declared `weak` to avoid reference cycles.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest as a good programming practice to name your classes with an uppercase, that is: "Game" instead of "game" and your protocols as well: "SettingsChanger" instead of "settingsChanger". Your method naming conventions seem also to need some improvement, just take 30 minutes time and read Apples "Cocoa Guidelines For Cocoa" [link to the "Cocoa Guidelines For Cocoa document"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html)